# Set $httpProvider default headers after user authentification

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am considering to add a default header for the $http service, which value is an access token that will be generated after user authentification.

```
module.config('$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider'){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['XSRF-AUTH'] = 
        "some accessToken to be generated later"; 
}
```

Problem is, the `config()` block is applied when Angular bootstraps its core components. Is there a way to alter `$ĥttpProvider` dynamically ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can change the default header through the $http object during runtime instead of the $httpProvider.  For example you can do the following outside of a config block:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['XSRF-AUTH'] = "access token";
```

Check out the $http api docs for more details http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers.

Comment: this is nice, the only problem is where to put it. You could put it in module load, but what if you have multiple modules which may or may not be loaded together. when I put this code on the page after angular.js was loaded I get "$http is not defined"

Comment: Sonic Soul, not sure if I understand your question, but you need to put it somewhere where you can use dependency injection to get a reference to $http (i.e. controller, run, service, etc...).  Where you put it would depend on your application.